# I can assign double to string?

Tags: c++

According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/) page, there are five ways to assign something to a string:

```
          string (1) string& operator= (const string& str);
        c-string (2) string& operator= (const char* s);
       character (3) string& operator= (char c);
initializer list (4) string& operator= (initializer_list<char> il);
            move (5) string& operator= (string&& str) noexcept;
```

Then why could I compile the text below? Which of this options was used by compiler?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s;
  double d = 1.0;
  s = d; 
  std::cout << s << std::endl; 
}
```

And this is not just a senseless question - I've spent long hours trying to find this `s = d` assignment in my code. It should have been `s = std::to_string(d)` of course.

Compiler: GCC 4.8.4.

Comment: What is printed? What is `s`?

Comment: do you really mean assign or do you mean **convert** double to string?

Comment: @Alex - It was assignment in my code

Comment: I suspect the compiler performs the following conversion: `double` -> `int` -> `char`.

Comment: @OferArial - garbage is printed

Comment: What garbage exactly?

Comment: It's not garbage, it's a one followed by en end-of-line character -- `\1` then `\n`.

Comment: @HEKTO [It is not garbage](http://ideone.com/pOpttq)

Comment: @RSahu: It's `double` -> `int` -> `char`, and not `double` -> `char`?

Comment: @KeithThompson, `double` -> `char` it is. *A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s;
  double d = 1.0;
  char j = d;
  s = j; 
  std::cout << s << std::endl; 
}
```

So you will output a `\1` followed by a line ending.

If you're using G++, specify `-Wconversion` to catch things like this.

> f.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   f.cpp:8:7: warning: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘double’ may alter its value [-Wfloat-conversion]
>      s = d;

Comment: Not a single warning with `-Wall`? Wow. MSVC /W4 says: "warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'char', possible loss of data"

Comment: @RustyX - yes, I compiled with -Wall

Answer (score 4):

It performs this conversion: `double -> char` and consequently uses the following overload:

```
character (3) string& operator= (char c);
```

I tested this scanning your output with `od`:

```
> ./a.out | od -c
0000000 001  \n
```